# MVC 3 escaping and unescaping the @

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to make dynamic CSS import:

```
@foreach (string cssUrl in Model.Css)
{
    @@import url(@Url.Content(cssUrl));
}
```

However this does not work, the @import is escaped but @Url... should not be! What now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place plain text in a `<text>` tag:

```
@foreach (string cssUrl in Model.Css)
{
    <text>@@import url(</text> @Url.Content(cssUrl)<text>);</text>
}
```

And this might work as well (haven't tried though):

```
@foreach (string cssUrl in Model.Css)
{
    @@import url(@:@Url.Content(cssUrl));
}
```

Note that the `<text></text>` tag will not be rendered. Here's a [Razor Syntax Quick Reference by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just render link tags for each url like this:

```
@foreach (string url in Model.Css)
{
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content(url)" />
}
```